# Change color on text with CSS

Tags: css, text, colors

I've been trying to change the text color in the tiles on my frontpage (http://holtumdata.dk)
You can see them, when you hold your mouse over for example "IT-Service", the text there, is the one I want to change the color on.

I've tried adding

```
color: #ffffff;
```

to

```
.portfolio_item .ql_hover > .ql_hover_content > div {
```

and/or

```
.portfolio_item .ql_hover > .ql_hover_content {
```

Nothing changed.

Am I trying in the wrong place, or should I issue another code to change the text color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `<h2>` heading color.. try this way:

```
.portfolio_item .ql_hover > .ql_hover_content > div h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    padding: 1.15385em;
}
```

/--If you want to change the text color inside the `p` element--/

```
.portfolio_item .ql_hover > .ql_hover_content > div p {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    padding: 1.15385em;
}
```

Comment: I only want to change the color of the text, not the H2.

Comment: then replace `<h2>` with `<p>` tag.. is that you want?

Comment: Marked as answer, was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this: 
`.portfolio_item .ql_hover > .ql_hover_content > div { color: #fff;}`

Comment: Added color: #fff; to .ql_hover_content > div, nothing changed.
Didn't add it with { color: #fff;}
Because I already have a padding there.

So it's like 
.portfolio_item .ql_hover > .ql_hover_content > div {
  padding: 1.15384615384615em;
  color: #fff;

}

Answer (score 0):

```
.ql_hover_content > div:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```